# How to manage a custom post type archive as a page?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, urls, custom-post-type-archives

Is there a way to manage a custom post type archive from the Page editing view?

I need to retain a certain url structure (so I need the formal wp archive), but also to be able to add images and content to the archive page from the admin.

Comment: have you considered using an archive template and changing the archive URL in the registration, then using the description and term meta? Either to store the content/images or choose a page to take the content from?

Comment: @Tom J Nowell hi, use a fake page can a viable solution, I already considered it. But I was hoping if maybe there was a way to really manage an archive content with pages. Indeed, considering the wordpress mechanics, I know it would be surprising... :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: @TomJNowell  
Can we show postype name or label as headings on frontend?

Comment: an archive isn't a page though, whatever you do you'll need to build it yourself, there's no 'built in' stuff to do it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: it's not possible. See comments above for workarounds.